# Skype crashes if run with normal user - no problem with root

Tags: permissions, skype

Running skype on AMD64 : **linux32 skype**.
If I use a normal account to connect skype, it crashes upon connecting, at the exact moment it is trying to play a sound file. My console then displays Aborted.

When I launch it as root user, I have no problem in connecting, and I can chat (text) and receive audio.

Tried `rm ~/.Skype/shared.xml` on normal user to no avail.
Tried also `chmod ugo-r libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3` as root but still crashing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Dumb me, last time I installed skype on 64bit, there was no 64bit version available. Now, I can see one at skype.com. Downloading and installing...

Comment: Installed skype2.2 64bit. No crash after connexion. Audio output OK. Microphone not working but that's another matter.

Comment: I've moved my comment into an answer so you can mark it as accepted.  As for your mic issue, you may consider posting that as another question, as this question is for it crashing when run as normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing the 64-bit version of Skype may fix your crashing issues.